Analyzing limiting case in a statics problem
consider the following problem from mechanics by Davd Morin:
"A ladder of length L and mass M has its bottom end attached to the
ground by a pivot. It makes an angle θ with the horizontal and is held
up by a massless stick of length l that is also attached to the ground by a
pivot (see Fig. 2.22). The ladder and the stick are perpendicular to each
other. Find the force that the stick exerts on the ladder."

The solution comes out to be $$F=\frac{MgL}{2l}\sin{\theta}$$
But as $\theta$ approaches $0$ should $F$ not approach $\frac{MgL}{2d}$ where d is the distance between the pivots of the stick and the ladder because then the stick would behave like a small pivot, and will have to balance the torque due to the weight of the ladder?

Did you do a free body diagram?

Voting to reopen. This is a conceptual question and so allowed by policy.

@JohnAlexiou how did you draw that free body diagram?

@ John Alexiou: To help in taking moments from your sketch please indicate the point of application of force F and its direction.

@AarushSaharan - I used powerpoint for the diagram.


Take the sum of the torques abbaut point A , you obtain
$$ M\,g\,\cos(\theta)\frac L2-F\,x=0$$
thus
$$ F=\frac {M\,g\,\cos(\theta)\frac L2}{x}\tag 1$$
with $~x=\frac {l}{\tan(\theta)}~$ you obtain
$$F=\frac{M\,g\,L}{2\,l}\sin(\theta)$$
but if $~\theta\mapsto 0~$ then $~x\mapsto\infty~$ and from equation (1) $~F\mapsto 0~$ as it schuld be .
with
$$ d=\sqrt{x^2+l^2}$$
thus if $~x\mapsto\infty~\Rightarrow~d\mapsto\infty$  and the force $~F$ for $~\theta=0~$ will be  zero

Instead of making x approach infinity, can we not make l approach zero so that the ratio x stays constant? For example we use a smaller rod for a smaller angle. Is that allowed?

There's nothing wrong here. Morin's answer, and your answer, are
$$F = \frac{MgL}{2} \frac{\sin \theta}{\ell}, \qquad F = \frac{MgL}{2} \frac{1}{d}.$$
However, by drawing a right triangle you can see that $\ell = d \sin \theta$, so the two answers agree.

Both you and the Morin solution are correct, the only thing is, as $\theta$ goes to 0, so does $l$. This means we must look closer to see the limit of $F$ as $\theta$ goes to zero.
If you fix the distance between where the stick and ladder touch the ground and call that $d$, then you have $ d \sin \theta = l$ or in other words, $\sin(\theta)/l = 1/d$. This means that as $\theta$ goes to zero that we have $F = MgL/2d$ which is what you get.

but how can dMgL/2 equal zero. that is what  do not understand

I made a mistake, the $d$ should be in the denominator. And the force should not go to 0 because it will always have to balance the torque applied by gravity if we have that $d=L/2$ then we get $F = Mg$ which we would expect as this is just a balancing rod.

So because its a static problem no nett torque is in the system.
The torque from gravity (the force resulting in a torque is the part of gravity perpendicular to the ladder)
$$\tau_g = r\times F_g = \frac{1}{2}L\cdot Mg \cos\theta$$
and the torque that the stick exerts on the ladder is found by first deriving the position of the stick ladder intersection:
$$x = \frac{l}{\tan\theta}$$
and thus results in a torque
$$\tau_F = r\times F = F \frac{l}{\tan\theta}$$
because the stick is perpendicular to the ladder.
so the no nett torque requirement is fullfilled when
$$0 = \frac{1}{2}L\cdot Mg \cos\theta - F \frac{l}{\tan\theta}$$
note the minus sign because gravity is working in the opposite direction as the stick force so. Leading to
$$F = \frac{MgL}{2l}\sin\theta$$
Now looking at what would happen when $\theta = 0$ the position $x\rightarrow \infty$ as $\tan0=0$ so therefore this solution cannot be used in that case.

"this solution can not be used in that case"    We are only taking the limiting value of theta as is becomes very small but not equal to zero so I think the solution can be used.

You are right. I meant for $\theta=0$ the solution doesn't  make sense anymore. Because it would mean the ladder would lay flat on the ground but at the same time offset by the stick in the verticle direction by a length $l$. I must admit that I do not really get the $Mgl/2d$ argument you made, but I hope you see what I am trying to explain.

I do get that but it does not answer my question

Okay, so could you maybe send a drawing what you mean with distance $d$ then because that is what I do not understand. Maybe also give some more intuition why the force should approach $MgL/2d$.
